# Only first category!

Tags: categories

I have a category organized like this:

- sport

  - football
  - basketball
  - volleyball
- news

  - economy
  - world
  - country

And I want to display only the *sport* and *news* root categories, but I don’t know how.

Comment: Your question is not understandable? what you really want?

Comment: I whont print only parent category!

Comment: Does this mean "You want to print root categories?" Please show your code what you have until now it will explain your context too.

Comment: and where do you want to display it? What do you want to do?

Comment: just second ....

Comment: This display me all category from specific id.
<code>
<?php // create a custom wordpress query
query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=3");?>
</code>

And like i said i whont display only root category not child!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display the parent Categories themselves, and not their posts, correct? [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) is what you need.

```
$top_level_categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'parent' => 0, // This will get ONLY top level items
    'hide_empty' => false // This will make sure even empty categories are returned
) );
print_r( $top_level_categories );
```

Comment: thx, i check....

Answer (score 0):

A list of Categories, excluding any Sub-categories can be displayed by the following code. Don't be afraid of the huge list of arguments, they are not mandatory.

```
         <?php $args = array(
            'show_option_all'    => '',
            'show_option_none'   => '',
            'orderby'            => 'ID', 
            'order'              => 'ASC',
            'show_count'         => 0,
            'hide_empty'         => 0, 
            'child_of'           => 0,
            'exclude'            => '0',
            'echo'               => 1,
            'selected'           => 0,
            'hierarchical'       => 1, 
            'name'               => 'category',
            'id'                 => '',
            'class'              => 'postform',
            'depth'              => 1,
            'tab_index'          => 0,
            'taxonomy'           => 'category',
            'title_li' => __( '' ),
            'hide_if_empty'      => false
        ); ?>

        <ul class="top-level">
            <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
        </ul>
```

The parent-child category viewing is controlled by `'depth' => 1,`.

> Codex: [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).

Comment: Yehh  I'm afraid. Time to make a difference.

Comment: Category 1 can be renamed; it's just the default category.  (For instance, I've renamed mine "So It Goes".)

Comment: @PatJ: Yap, right you are. It can even be deleted, and there'd be no catId#1. :) Ok. I better put nothing into the `exclude` parameter.

Comment: Or do something like `'exclude' => get_cat_ID( 'Uncategorized' )`, so that if category 1 is still called 'Uncategorized', it'll get excluded.